# GROUP BY ID and select MAX

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by, max, seq

Good Evening,
I am working on a table like this in Oracle:

| ID | BALANCE | SEQ |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 102 | 13 |
| 1 | 119 | 15 |
| 2 | 50 | 4 |
| 3 | 20 | 11 |
| 3 | 15 | 10 |
| 3 | 45 | 9 |
| 4 | 90 | 5 |
| 5 | 67 | 20 |
| 5 | 12 | 19 |
| 6 | 20 | 1 |

I want to select, for each ID, the BALANCE having MAX(SEQ).

So final result would be:

| ID | BALANCE | SEQ |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 119 | 15 |
| 2 | 50 | 4 |
| 3 | 20 | 11 |
| 4 | 90 | 5 |
| 5 | 67 | 20 |
| 6 | 20 | 1 |

How can I do that?
I've tried several Group by queries but with no success.
Thanks for any help

Comment: Along with the problem you should **include the code you have up until this point** (*make some effort to answer your problem/question as [so] is not a code writing service*). After [doing more research](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) if you have a problem you can **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and providing a **[mcve]**. I suggest reading [*How do I ask a Good Question*](/help/how-to-ask) and [*Writing the Perfect Question*](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/). Also, be sure to take the [tour].

Comment: I can't post the query because the table I am working on is already the result of a long query, to which I need to add the logic I am asking here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One method is aggregation using `keep`:

```
select id,
       max(balance) keep (dense_rank first order by seq desc) as balance,
       max(seq)
from t
group by id;
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use normal `rank()`

```
SELECT ID, BALANCE, SEQ FROM ( 
select 
ID, BALANCE, SEQ, RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY SEQ DESC)  ranks
from t 
) WHERE ranks = 1
```

sample demo

```
    SELECT ID, BALANCE, SEQ FROM ( 
SELECT ID, BALANCE, SEQ, RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY SEQ DESC)  ranks 
FROM ( 
SELECT 1 ID,    102 BALANCE,    13 SEQ FROM dual UNION all
SELECT 1,       119,    15  FROM dual UNION all
SELECT 2,       50,     4   FROM dual UNION all
SELECT 3,       20,     11  FROM dual UNION all
SELECT 3,       15,     10  FROM dual UNION all
SELECT 3,       45,     9   FROM dual UNION all
SELECT 4,       90,     5   FROM dual UNION all
SELECT 5,       67,     20  FROM dual UNION all
SELECT 5,       12,     19  FROM dual UNION all
SELECT 6,       20,     1   FROM dual 
)
) WHERE ranks = 1
```

you can add it in your Big query as below

```
SELECT ID, BALANCE, SEQ FROM ( 
select 
ID, BALANCE, SEQ, RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY SEQ DESC)  ranks
from (**YOUR BIG QUERY HERE**) 
) WHERE ranks = 1
```